# Insert multiple statements inside trigger mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to do inserts into multiple tables in MYSQL upon trigger. My code goes like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER createUsername AFTER INSERT ON UserDatabase
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO PushNotifications_Device (Username) VALUES (NEW.Username) 
INSERT INTO LoginDatabase (Username) VALUES (NEW.Username)
END
```

Basically the idea is to replicate the new `Username` (after coming into `UserDatabase`), into the `PushNotifications_Device` and `LoginDatabase` tables. But I am getting syntax errors.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the delimiters and the trigger should be as

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER createUsername AFTER INSERT ON UserDatabase
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO PushNotifications_Device (Username) VALUES (NEW.Username) ;
  INSERT INTO LoginDatabase (Username) VALUES (NEW.Username);
END;//

delimiter ;
```